# Looking to Convert seconds since epoch to readable date time (works on mac, not PC)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, unix

I have a a program that creates the following dataframe:

```
         datetime     open    high     low   close  volume
7995  1584143700000  267.690  267.69  267.53  267.60    5016
7996  1584143760000  267.600  267.62  267.36  267.53    9183
7997  1584143820000  267.530  267.53  267.40  267.44    8567
7998  1584143880000  267.485  267.70  267.42  267.46   28488
7999  1584143940000  267.450  267.50  267.11  267.45   13395
```

On my Mac, I use the following statement:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'].astype(int), unit='ms')
```

to convert the datetime column into UTC which works perfectly and returns:

```
                datetime     open    high     low   close  volume
7995 2020-03-13 23:55:00  267.690  267.69  267.53  267.60    5016
7996 2020-03-13 23:56:00  267.600  267.62  267.36  267.53    9183
7997 2020-03-13 23:57:00  267.530  267.53  267.40  267.44    8567
7998 2020-03-13 23:58:00  267.485  267.70  267.42  267.46   28488
7999 2020-03-13 23:59:00  267.450  267.50  267.11  267.45   13395
```

When I run the program on a PC - it returns values in the 1960's (prior to epoch time), so I am wondering what changes or line I would need to have the correct output.

Row 7999 returns on PC:

```
         datetime     open    high     low   close  volume
7999  1969-12-23  267.450  267.50  267.11  267.45   13395
```

Why and what is responsible for the variance between systems and how can I fix for windows?

Answer (score 1):

I've just attempted to run the following 2 lines on a PC, it runs just fine, producing `2020-03-13 23:59:00` result. TBH, i am unfamiliar with pandas data frames, but my best guess would be change `astype(int)` to either `astype(int64)` or something similar, suspecting an int may be 32 bits.

Please note, this is not a baseless guess. `1584143940000` is `0x170D65639A0`, trimmed down to 32 bit it's `0xD65639A0`, casted into signed 32 bit int its `-698992224`, `pd.to_datetime(-698992224, unit='ms')` gives you the very `1969-12-23` you get.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.to_datetime(1584143940000, unit='ms'))
```

Edit: suspicion confirmed by running the following:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy

df = pd.DataFrame([1584143940000], columns=['x'])

print(pd.to_datetime(df.x[0], unit='ms'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.x[0].astype(int), unit='ms'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.x[0].astype(numpy.int64), unit='ms'))
```

And getting this output:

```
2020-03-13 23:59:00
1969-12-23 21:50:07.776000
2020-03-13 23:59:00
```

Comment: thank you for your continuous edits and idea. I changed datatype from integer to float, and it worked perfectly. Prior to that, I was trying your edits and attempting to convert integer to no avail. I then determined that it worked fine on my system when printing integer.

Comment: @aetherthought what i've listed here is an actual run on my machine, of the actual code listed. Please note, the important part may not be the machine, but having a 32 or 64 bit version of python itself, and i happened to have the 32 bit version here.

Comment: BTW, wanna reproduce on any machine? Try astype(numpy.int32)